# How to Evaluate Interaction Effects in Propensity Score-Matched Samples:

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, propensity-scores, matching

Suppose I want to study the association between an exposure X and outcome Y, and I have used the propensity score to match each exposed subject with those unexposed but with similar characteristics based on a set of covariates (C1​,C2​,C3​).

My question is, if I want to additionally test the interaction between X and C1​ in the matched sample,

A. Can I directly test this interaction in the matched sample?

B. Or    must I include the moderator in the matching and run
stratified       analyses to test for effect modification (as shown
here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/vignettes/estimating-effects.html#moderation-analysis)?
If this is the case, how should I run the analyses when the
moderator    is continuous?

What are the pros and cons of both methods A and B? I have read many different posts but see many different answers.